# Create formula to get a value

Tags: combinatorics

I have clients whichs pay a monthly fee. I would like to know the accumulative total for a given quantity of month for a given fee. Plus I get 2 new clients every month.

Let's say a client pays 25€/month, if I want to know how much will this client pay for 4 months, I use to do this:

```
Month 1    Month 2    Month 3   Month 4 
25€     +    25€   +    25€   +  25€  
25€     +    25€   +    25€   +  25€ 
             25€   +    25€   +  25€ 
             25€   +    25€   +  25€ 
                        25€   +  25€ 
                        25€   +  25€ 
                                 25€ 
                                 25€
```

This gives me 500€. This means that if I get 2 new clientes every mothn I will get 500€ at the end of the fourth month.

As you can see this is time wasting. Is there a way to create a formula to enter these values and get what I need?

Value of **fee**: $f

Number of **months**: $m

Number of **monthly new clients**: $mnc

Comment: @MarcoB why not vote for migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the time being, pretend you get one new client per month. (If you get 7, the answer will be 7 times as large).

Your table then looks like a triangle with m rows and m columns, hence it has 
$$
\frac{m(m+1)}{2}
$$
entries, each of which is some amount $f$. So the total amount there is 
$$
f\frac{m(m+1)}{2}
$$
And if there are $k$ new clients per month, it's 
$$
k \cdot f \cdot \frac{m(m+1)}{2}
$$
where $k$ is the number of new clients, $f$ is the fee paid by each per month, and $m$ is the number of months.